# Jenkins Installation on Google Compute Engine VM Instance

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to install jenkins and all of its dependencies on VM instance. I installed tomcat on VM, But, I am unable to access it using web UI. I have also created a firewall rule and allowing access to default port 8080. But still facing the issue that:

This site can’t be reached 10.128.0.2 took too long to respond.

Could you please help me with installation of jenkins and all of its dependencies.

I have already allowed http and https request to VM. Installed tomcat 9 using below link:
http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.23/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz

Comment: what's the return of : curl http://localhost:8080

Comment: Most of the time all the port other than 443(https) and 80(http) are blocked. Check if your jenkins is running on 8080 port, If yes then you need to do proxy pass from 80 to 8080. You can achieve it using nginx very easily.

Comment: Which URL did you try to access in your browser?

Comment: curl localhost:8080 is not responding anything. But tomcat is up and running. And I have also made 8080 port available through firewall rules. To open in Browser, I am giving <VM_external_IP>:8080

Comment: I installed the apache 2 now and tried to connect to localhost. Now output of localhost:8080 is:  Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:
  
Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

Answer (score 0):

I opened the 8080 port using firewall rule and it worked for me. Go to VPC network and under Firewall section create firewall rule for that particular vm.
Under protocols and ports after tcp text boc enter 8080 and save the changes.